# Avsession gives "Memory warning "

Tags: ios

I am using Avsession to capture images .
while i capture first image i will redirect user to apply effects on it and then get back to my capture image screen and i will preview image on cam capture screen .Then i will allow user to capture 3 more images and i will preview all images on cam capture screen. while i capturing my third image i will receive memory warning.

**After Capturing Every image i will crop image to resize.**

I have write below code in viewdidload

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:cameraFlashMode];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
    [self.btnFlashLight setHidden:NO];
}
else
    [self.btnFlashLight setHidden:YES];

cameraMode = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
firstImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
firstImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
secondImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
secondImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
thirdImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
thirdImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
forthImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
forthImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
if ([capturedImages count] == 0)
    [self.btnNext setEnabled:NO];

if ([self captureManager] == nil) {
    CamCaptureManager *manager = [[CamCaptureManager alloc] init];
    [self setCaptureManager:manager];

    [[self captureManager] setDelegate:self];

    if ([[self captureManager] setupSession]) {
        // Create video preview layer and add it to the UI
        newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[[self captureManager] session]];
        UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];
        CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
        [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];
        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
        [viewLayer insertSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];

        UIBezierPath *fullScreenPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [fullScreenPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:[GeneralDeclaration generalDeclaration].cameraMaskFrame byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners                                                                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f)]];
        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
        maskLayer.path = fullScreenPath.CGPath;
        maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        maskLayer.opacity = 0.6f;
        maskLayer.lineWidth = 1.0f;
        maskLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        [viewLayer insertSublayer:maskLayer above:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];

        [self setCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];
        [[self captureManager] session ].sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [[[self captureManager] session] startRunning];
        });
    }
}
```

**I have written Below code to process captured Image:**

```
[[self captureManager] captureStillImage];
     UIView *flashView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self videoPreviewView] frame]];
    [flashView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[[self view] window] addSubview:flashView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4f
                     animations:^{
                         [flashView setAlpha:0.f];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [flashView removeFromSuperview];
                     }
     ];

    firstImage.image = nil;
    secondImage.image = nil;
    thirdImage.image = nil;
    forthImage.image = nil;

    //firstImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    secondImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    thirdImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    forthImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    for (UIImageView *subview in [firstImage subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (UIImageView *subview in [secondImage subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (UIImageView *subview in [thirdImage subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    for (UIImageView *subview in [forthImage subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

for(int i = 0; i < [capturedImages count]; i++)
{
    UIImage *removeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"remove_image.png"];
    UIImageView *removeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:removeImage];
    removeImageView.tag = i;
    [removeImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(firstImage.bounds.size.width/2, firstImage.bounds.size.height/2)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *removeImageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeImage_Tapped:)];
    removeImageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    removeImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [removeImageView addGestureRecognizer:removeImageTap];

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            firstImage.image = [capturedImages objectAtIndex:i];
            //[firstImage addSubview:removeImageView];
            break;
        case 1:
            secondImage.image = [capturedImages objectAtIndex:i];
            [secondImage addSubview:removeImageView];
            break;
        case 2:
            thirdImage.image = [capturedImages objectAtIndex:i];
            [thirdImage addSubview:removeImageView];
            break;
        case 3:
            forthImage.image = [capturedImages objectAtIndex:i];
            [forthImage addSubview:removeImageView];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Set property `sessionPreset` like this:

```
[yourcamera session].sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
```

This will not totally remove memory warning but may help to reduce it.

Comment: I have also Implemented dealloc function as i am using ARC & also dealloc all session while i move to next screen .This will help me to reduce warnings. Thanks @Nirmit